# PDF Size maximum limit in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

i have encountered a problem maximum page size allowed in iTextsharp, so when i try to generate a document with size superior to 14 400 , i get an message error `the.page.size.must.be.smaller.than.14400.by.14400.its.1.by.2`, i tried to play with `userunits` like [described here](http://itextsharp.10939.n7.nabble.com/Big-pdf-pagesize-cause-problems-td3937.html) , but i have not found a solution.

i generate the PDF by merging file in one page using `AddTemplate()`, i think to scale the pdf dimensions by 1/4 for eg, and set userunits to 4, but i think that i should scale the imported pages too , any help in this way because i don't know how to scale imported pages, i not sure if this the right solution.

```
 PdfImportedPage imp1 = wr.GetImportedPage(r1, 1); 
 wr.DirectContent.AddTemplate(imp1,(float)(x*cm),(float)(y*cm));
```

Any help please or any suggestion

Comment: You say *i not sure if this the right solution* --- have you tested it meanwhile? is the result according to your requirements? If not, what's the issue there? Your question in its current state makes it difficult to help you.

Comment: i cannot test it because i don't know how to scale imported page, can you help me to scale it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you make clear in your comment that your problem in testing your solution (`DirectContent.AddTemplate` applied to a `PdfImportedPage`) actually is that you *don't know how to scale imported page*, here a pointer to an example that shows how to do right that.

Have a look at the sample [NUpTool.cs](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter06&ex=NUpTool) translated from the matching Java sample [NUpTool](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=115) from [chapter 6](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) of [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/). The variable `factor` here describes the scaling factor.